# telling homebrew to use is own installed version of ruby@2.0

Tags: homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I have High Sierra Beta 6 Installed on my Mac Pro.

High sierra beta comes with Ruby 2.2 and `brew doctor` complains about it since it was tested only with ruby 2.0.

I can install ruby 2.0 with homebrew, is there a way to tell homebrew to actually use that version instead of the ruby version that comes with the OS ?

Comment: There’s no way to do that. High Sierra is still in beta so it’s normal it’s not fully supported by Homebrew.

Comment: @bfontaine - good enough answer for me! :) please post it as an answer so i'll accept it

Comment: I just did it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no way to do that. High Sierra is still in beta so it’s normal it’s not fully supported by Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change the ruby version used by homebrew. Just add these 2 lines to your .bash_profile

```
export HOMEBREW_DEVELOPER="yes"
export HOMEBREW_RUBY_PATH="/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby"
```

Comment: Note that this is a feature targeted at Homebrew maintainers and it might break things, so use it at your own risk.

Comment: Yes but taking in consideration that you are using a macOS beta and Homebrew with a untested ruby build, this will be your best option.

Comment: The danger is to forget about it; upgrading to a stable macOS version won’t wipe these two lines from the `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

Just updated to High Sierra. I experienced the same Ruby warnings after upgrade. What I did was:

```
1. brew doctor -- warnings shown
2. brew update
3. brew doctor -- no more warnings
```